# Puppet apt site.pp h

Tags: puppet

New to puppet, so probably something simple. Cannot understand why the below manifest does not work.
When run on an agent I get the following error:

***Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '='; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:14***

```
node 'linuxlab' {

include apt

apt::unattended_upgrades {
  origins             = $::apt::params::origins,
  update              = '1',
  download            = '1',
  upgrade             = '1',
  autoclean           = '7',
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `=` to pass parameters to a class.
`=>` is used for that.
`=` is used to assign values to variables.
So that code should be changed to:

```
node 'linuxlab' {

  include apt

  apt::unattended_upgrades {
    origins             => $::apt::params::origins,
    update              => '1',
    download            => '1',
    upgrade             => '1',
    autoclean           => '7',
  }
}
```